# How can I see if a user has a role stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm making a role assignment command for my bot, so a user can type `h.addrole @user @role` I'm trying to make it if the user has the role, it outputs saying `This user already has this role!` Whenever I try using the command, it always outputs
 `(node:5224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: userToModify.hasRole is not a function`

My code is as follows:

```
} if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "addrole")) {
  let userToModify = message.mentions.members.first();
  let roleToAdd = message.mentions.roles.first();
  if (userToModify.hasRole(roleToAdd)) return message.channel.send("This user already has this role!")
  if (!args) return message.channel.send("Please enter a mentioned user and a mentioned role to assign (e.g h.addrole @Brickman @Moderator")
  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("You do not have permission for this!")
  userToModify.addRole(roleToAdd); 
  return message.channel.send("Succesfully added role " + roleToAdd + " to member " + userToModify + "!");
```

Comment: May be you want to modify this line of code, 
`let userToModify = message.mentions.members.first;`

Comment: Take a look at [this discord.js guide](https://anidiots.guide/understanding/roles#check-if-a-member-has-a-role)

Answer (score 1):

Like it says...`hasRole` isn't a function.

Instead, try it like this:
`if (userToModify.has(roleToAdd.id)) return message.channel.send("This user already has this role!")`